# Отменить событие скрипта после закрытия окна и запустить повторно при клике на элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добра. 
Честно — я откровенно не сильна в скриптах; так, на начальном уровне: что-то отредактировать, написать простенькое. И посему в итоге столкнулась с такой проблемой:

На данный момент я верстаю портфолио. В нём есть блок с несколькими элементами, по клике на которые появляется модальное окно, а в нём галерея изображений ([скриншот](http://image.prntscr.com/image/730f73cffad741699acc785b272a97ab.png)). При клике на миниатюру — исходное изображение заменяется на выбранное.

Проблема в том, что когда я закрываю модальное окно и открываю другой проект, то вместо исходного изображения, отображается выбранное в прошлый раз.

Можно ли сбросить как-то это событие, чтобы изображение, заданное в HTML-коде, отображалось как есть при открытии модального окна, а не отображалось то, что было выбрано раньше? То есть, для каждого блока (галереи) у меня есть исходное изображение (указано в div.fullImage), которое отображается автоматически и меняется только по клику на миниатюру. Но сейчас оно заменяется на то, что было выбрано активным в момент, когда последний раз открывалось модальное окно и подгружалась галерея.

HTML:

```
<!-- галерея -->
<div id="allDiamondImage">
  <div class="galleryBox">
    <div class="thumbnails">
      <a href="images/design_works/diamond/diamondDark.jpg" class="active">
        <img src="images/design_works/diamond/diamondDark.jpg" alt="diamond dark page">
      </a>

      <a href="images/design_works/diamond/diamond.jpg">
        <img src="images/design_works/diamond/diamond.jpg" alt="diamond page">
      </a>

      <a href="images/design_works/diamond/sketch.jpg">
        <img src="images/design_works/diamond/sketch.jpg" alt="sketch">
      </a>

      <a href="images/design_works/diamond/vector.png">
        <img src="images/design_works/diamond/vector.jpg" alt="vector">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="view">
      <div class="fullImage">
        <a href="#" class="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

        <img src="images/design_works/diamond/diamondDark.jpg" alt="full">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--галерея // end-->
```

Скрипт:

```
$(function gallery() {
    $('.thumbnails a').click(function() {                               // При нажатии на миниатюру

        var images = $(this).find('img');
        var imgSrc = images.attr('src');

        $(".fullImage img").attr({ src: imgSrc });                         // Подменяем адрес большого изображения на адрес выбранного

        $(this).siblings('a').removeClass('active');                       // Удаляем класс .active со ссылки чтоб убрать рамку
        images.parent().addClass('active');                                // Добавляем класс .active на выбранную миниатюру
        return false;
    });

    $('.next').click(function() {                                        // При нажатии на кнопку "вперед"
        var count = $('.thumbnails a').length;                             // Общее количество изображений
        var n = parseInt($('.thumbnails a').index($('.active')) + 1);      // Порядковый номер текущего изображения
        var activeImg = $('.thumbnails .active');                          // Активное на данный момент изображение
        var nextSrc;

        if (count != n) {                                                  // - Если изображение не последнее
            nextSrc = activeImg.next().find('img').attr('src');              // В переменную записывается адрес следующего изображения
            $('.thumbnails .active').removeClass('active');                  // Удаляется класс .active с предыдущей миниатюры
            activeImg.next().addClass('active');                             // На миниатюру следующего изображения вешается класс .active
        } else {                                                           // - Если текущее изображение последнее в списке
            nextSrc = $('.thumbnails a').first().find('img').attr('src');    // В переменную записывается адрес первого изображения
            $('.thumbnails .active').removeClass('active');                  // Удаляется класс .active с предыдущей миниатюры
            $('.thumbnails a').first().addClass('active');                   // На первую миниатюру вешается класс .active
        }
        $('.fullImage img').attr({ src: nextSrc });                        // Подменяем адрес большого изображения на адрес следующего
        return false;
    });


    $('.prev').click(function() {                                        // При нажатии на кнопку "назад"
        var count = $('.thumbnails a').length;                             // Общее количество изображений
        var n = parseInt($('.thumbnails a').index($('.active')) + 1);      // Порядковый номер текущего изображения
        var activeImg = $('.thumbnails .active');                          // Активное на данный момент изображение
        var prevSrc;

        if (n != 1) {                                                      // - Если текущее изображение не первое
            prevSrc = activeImg.prev().find('img').attr('src');              // В переменную записывается адрес предыдущего изображения           
            $('.thumbnails .active').removeClass('active');                  // Удаляется класс .active активной до этого миниатюры
            activeImg.prev().addClass('active');                             // На миниатюру изображения слева вешается класс .active
        } else {                                                           // - Если текущее изображение первое
            prevSrc = $('.thumbnails a:last').find('img').attr('src');       // В переменную записывается адрес последнего изображения
            $('.thumbnails .active').removeClass('active');                  // Удаляется класс .active с предыдущей миниатюры
            $('.thumbnails a:last').addClass('active');                      // На последнюю миниатюру вешается класс .active
        }
        $('.fullImage img').attr({ src: prevSrc });                        // Подменяется адрес большого изображения на адрес следующего
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: У меня по клику на картинке происходит переход на саму картинку.

Comment: Так и должно быть: я привела скриншот в пример для того, чтобы было понятно как это выглядит визуально. Весь необходимый код показан; но с решением уже помогли, так что вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"при открытии модального окна" вызывайте

```
$($('текущая_галерея .thumbnails a')[0]).click();
```

Или дело в том, что у Вас на странице больше одного `'.fullimage img'`, и Вы им всем каждый раз устанавливаете атрибут `src` в

```
$(".fullImage img").attr({ src: ... });
```

Делайте:

```
$(this).closest('.galleryBox').find(".fullImage img").attr({ src: ... });
```

Comment: Да, проблема была в том, что использовалось несколько '.fullimage img'. Спасибо огромное, теперь всё отлично работает; так бы маялась ещё чёрт знает сколько.)

Comment: @justaway. Не за что. Успехов в программировании!